# Swapping pointers: equivalent of `std::unique_ptr::swap`

Tags: c++, go, swap, unique-ptr

I'm not sure how to translate C++ `std::unique_ptr::swap` into Go.

I am using [std::unique_ptr<T,Deleter>::swap](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/swap) in C++:

```cpp
std::unique_ptr<bool[]> maskA{new bool[num]};
std::unique_ptr<bool[]> maskB{new bool[num]};

// ...

maskA.swap(maskB); // Swap operation
```

Would I be missing something if I just use a simple `maskA, maskB = maskB, maskA` in Go?

```golang
maskA := make([]bool, num)
maskB := make([]bool, num)

// ...

maskA, maskB = maskB, maskA
```

Does this swap have the same functionality?

Comment: "*I want to double-check*" Double-check what? That `swap` does what it says it does?

Comment: @NicolBolas Double-checking whether `maskA, maskB = maskB, maskA` does the same thing as `std::unique_ptr::swap`, or am I missing something?

Comment: C++ `std::unique_ptr::swap` is a different beast: `Exchanges the contents of the unique_ptr object with those of x, transferring ownership of any managed object between them without destroying either.` and has nothing to do with Go. You need to be more clear on what you are asking here. in Go swap is just a swap and like  simple swap in C++: `temp=a; a=b; b=temp;` just in one line: `a, b = b, a`

Comment: @user3405291: So your question has nothing to do with `unique_ptr`, and is really just asking whether C++ allows you to swap things (not just `unique_ptr`s) the way Go does. You should edit and rephrase your question to make that clear.

Comment: You're comparing a basic shorthand feature of Go with a utility to handle pointer ownership in C++. These are completely unrelated. But yes, the code you showed will do the same thing, it's just that Go does not need pointer ownership utilities since it is a garbage collected language.

Comment: @Marc Thanks =) I posted your comment as answer before this question is closed. If you post your comment as answer, I will delete mine and will accept yours as the solution.

Comment: I've written an answer with a lot more details. Please read it carefully.

Comment: @Marc Sure :) Thanks =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The short answer:

This will be equivalent in terms of functionality but the actual performance implications are different. Use `*[]bool` for nearest equivalent.

#### Properties:

The [assignment with exchange](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignments) has the following properties:

- the values of `maskA` and `maskB` will be **exchanged**
- because these are slices, the underlying array of bools is **not copied**
- thanks to compiler optimizations, the slice descriptors **might** not be copied either

The last two points are important and due to the way slices are built:  they are small descriptors pointing to the underlying array. See [slice internals](https://blog.golang.org/slices-intro) for more details.

#### Differences between C++ and Go:

**In C++**, a `unique_ptr<foo>` always holds a `*foo` and the swap just involves exchanging addresses, this has predictable performance implications.

**In Go**, the type is whatever you give it, and the compiler will copy values. The amount of work depends on the type:

- If these are big (eg: arrays: `[1000]bool`) it could get expensive
- If they are slices as you have now (eg: `[]bool`), the slice descriptor will be copied.
- If they are pointers (eg: `*[]bool`), this will be the same as C++

So to be guaranteed equivalency to the C++ code, **you should be using a pointer to a bool slice** (`*[]bool`) as your Go types.

#### Go optimizations:

The Go compiler will try to optimize away the variable swap.

Here is a trivial example:

```
func main() {
  a := make([]bool, 0)
  b := make([]bool, 0)
  fmt.Println(a, b)
  a, b = b, a
  fmt.Println(a, b)
}
```

We can dump the optimization steps during compilation using `GOSSAFUNC=main go build .`

Looking at the resulting `ssa.html` file, we can see that the `a, b = b, a` line is dropped entirely and the following code is changed to something like `fmt.Println(b, a)`.

When this happens your swap becomes just coding nicety and has no performance implications, but **this will not always be the case** (compiler optimizations are very specialized, there are cases where it cannot do this. eg: swapping two struct field members cannot be optimized away).

#### Unequal comparison:

Comparing the two is a little bit strange. A closer equivalent in C++ would be two plain variables to be swapped (whether pointers or not). The main goal of a `unique_ptr` is to simplify object ownership and delete the underlying object when the `unique_ptr` goes out of scope.

Go has no equivalent to `unique_ptr` mostly because it does not need to, all memory is garbage collected.